# Google Compute VM Instance

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a new VM Instance based on the application instance : SQL Server 2017 Web on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.  My SQL Server instance works, but when I try to access Reporting Services Configuration Manager to set up reporting services, I am unable to connect.  If I try to install Reporting Services 2017, it asks me for a license.  I am however paying for a SQL Server license as part of my instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to clarify that "**SQL server on GCP**" license price is not included in your "Windows Server 2016 Datacenter" OS license. Also, note that

> Image [usage fee](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing?hl=en_US&_ga=2.151754426.-2077901908.1535997229#sql_server_pricing) is charged by Microsoft and billed by Google.

Also, see [pricing-for-sql-server](https://cloud.google.com/sql-server/#pricing-for-sql-server) for an idea of the associated license fee using "SQL Server Web". Please noted, that the Reporting Services component is included in SQL Server 2017 license, see [SQL Server Reporting Services Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/07/19/sql-server-2017-reporting-services-release-candidate-now-available/)

> [As we described with the release of CTP 2.1,](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2017/05/17/sql-server-2017-ctp-2-1-now-available/) we moved Reporting Services installation from the SQL Server installer to a separate installer. This is a packaging change, not a product change; access to SQL Server Reporting Services is still included with your SQL Server license. The new installation process keeps our packages lean and enables customers to deploy and update Reporting Services with zero impact on your SQL Server deployments and databases.

You may also use the [Billing Support Requests](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) form to contact Google billing support team to review your account.

Comment: According to the Google Documentation the VM Instance that was based on an Application Instance (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter adition plus SQL Server 2017 Web Edition), already contained SQL Server and the price per hour I was quoted included the SQL Server Licensing.  Because Reporting Services is a seperate installation, I installed it seperately, but it asked me for a license key, which I don't have as I bought the VM with SQL Server pre installed.

Comment: @Andy, are you able to provide a link to the documentation for clarity? Could you also confirm what you've already have deployed i.e. Windows Server 2016 Datacenter edition on a Windows VM instance in GCP or SQL Server 2017 Web Edition on Linux VM instance in GCP? I will be able to provide more clarification on this once I know how your environment is setup.